# Populate ListView using Retrofit 2

Tags: android, retrofit2

I'm trying to populate a ListView with a JSON from a server. I'm getting the data from the server but I can't seem to figure out how to put it in a ListView. The error I'm getting is in the onResponse.

It says: "Error:(84, 54) error: constructor JucatoriLiberiArrayAdapter in class JucatoriLiberiArrayAdapter cannot be applied to given types;
required: Context,ArrayList
found: FragmentActivity,Call>
reason: actual argument Call> cannot be converted to ArrayList by method invocation conversion"

I think I've tried almost every Alt+Enter fix there is. Also tried to change type from `Call<ArrayList<FreePlayers>` to just `ArrayList<>` or just `Call<>`.

This is my class:

```
   @Override
        public void onActivityCreated(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);


            HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
            interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(interceptor).build();

            final Retrofit builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .client(client)
                    .baseUrl(ROOT)
                    .build();

            REST_CLIENT = builder.create(API.class);


            final Call<FreePlayers> request = REST_CLIENT.getFreePlayers(1);
            request.enqueue(new Callback<FreePlayers>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(final Call<FreePlayers> call, final Response<FreePlayers> response) {
                    ArrayList<FreePlayers> players = null;

                    players = call;

                    ListView lv = (ListView) getView().findViewById(android.R.id.list);

                    JucatoriLiberiArrayAdapter adapter = new JucatoriLiberiArrayAdapter(getActivity(),
                            players);

                    lv.setAdapter(adapter);


                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(final Call<FreePlayers> call, final Throwable t) {

                }
            });


        }
```

My API interface:

```
public interface API {

    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("/fan-sport/app-test/")
    Call<ArrayList<FreePlayers>> getFreePlayers(@Field("getFreePlayers") int freePlayers);

}
```

And this is my custom adapter:

```
public class JucatoriLiberiArrayAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<FreePlayers> players;




    public JucatoriLiberiArrayAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<FreePlayers> playersList) {
        super();

        this.context = context;
        this.players = playersList;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(final int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(final int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {



        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        if (convertView == null) {

            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view_jucatori_liberi, null);


            TextView playerName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            playerName.setText((CharSequence) players.get(position));


        }


        return convertView;

    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `onResponse()` you receive a `Call` object wheras your adapter expects a `List<FreePlayers>`, the response argument is the list of players you want to give to your adapter.

Try this code:

```
final Call<List<FreePlayers>> request = REST_CLIENT.getFreePlayers(1);

request.enqueue(new Callback<List<FreePlayers>>() {

    @Override
    public void onResponse(final Call<List<FreePlayers>> call, final Response<List<FreePlayers>> response) {

        ArrayList<FreePlayers> players = null;

        players = response.body();

        ListView lv = (ListView) getView().findViewById(android.R.id.list);

        JucatoriLiberiArrayAdapter adapter = new JucatoriLiberiArrayAdapter(getActivity(),
                        players);

        lv.setAdapter(adapter);


    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(final Call<FreePlayers> call, final Throwable t) {

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

call is assgined to players, but players type is `ArrayList<FreePlayers>` and call type is `Call<List<FreePlayers>`. Not the same. The adapter expects `ArrayList<FreePlayers>`.

Answer (score 0):

You're declaring

```
Call<FreePlayers>,
```

but expect to receive

```
Call<ArrayList<FreePlayers>>.
```

Also, you're Adapter is broken. These methods should look something like:

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    if (players == null) return 0;
    return players.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(final int position) {
    if (players == null || players.size() == 0) return null; 
    return players.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(final int position) {
    return getItem(position).getId(); // or something like an id that suits you.
}
```